# connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused

Tags: java, spring, rest, curl, spring-restcontroller

I created a simple [`RestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html), using Spring (not Boot).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(UserRestController.REST_URL)
public class UserRestController extends AbstractUserController {

    static final String REST_URL = "/users";

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public User get(int id) {
      return super.get(id);
  }
}
```

But when I invoke this method and use curl I receive:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/users
Trying 127.0.0.1...
TCP_NODELAY set
connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Additionally:  I push MocMvc-test and it failed with following result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
  Expected :200
  Actual   :404
```

I run my app with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appCtx = new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/spring-app.xml")) {
 System.out.println("Bean definition names: " + 
  Arrays.toString(appCtx.getBeanDefinitionNames()));
UserRestController userRestController = 
  appCtx.getBean(UserRestController.class);
        System.out.println(userRestController.get(2));
    }
}
```

In the console I see the output of `System.out.println(userRestController.get(2));`
So my CRUD-methods works good.

Comment: Which server been used to deploy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl : connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027340/curl-connection-refused)

Comment: Did you start your Spring program? It should have printed the port that it is listening to. Show us the output of that (still running) program.

Comment: server...  I missed this detail...

Comment: Amongalen. I tried this advice (netstat -ln | grep 8080)  and see, that no app listening port 8080.

Comment: Andreas. Does it  mean, that I should to start spring with command line?

Comment: Did you defined a context name? Which server do you use?

Comment: Is the server running? I'm 99% sure that the server is not running.

Comment: and which ide are you using?

Comment: And what server can I use for this goal?

Comment: IntelliJ indea ultimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to attend an HTTP request with Spring without using Spring Boot, you need typically the following:

1. Use spring-webmvc dependency. I understood that you already have.
2. Package your application as a war. If you build with maven, you need to add the `<packaging>war</packaging>` sentence in your pom.xml
3. In your web.xml declare the [`org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html). You can also use the [`org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html) to register it.
4. Define the mappings and configuration in your application-context file or class if you use java-config.
5. Deploy your war file in a Servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty.

I put an example with Spring 5 [here](https://github.com/earth001/spring-core-certification-exercises/tree/master/spring-web).

You can found another example with Spring 4 [here](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-rest-service-example-using-restcontroller/).

Comment: I forgot a Dispatcher-servlet in web.xml!