# php curl Failed to connect to xxx port 5001: Connection refused

Tags: php, curl

This is my url: `http://xxx:5001/?messageId=2&baseId=1`

If I open it in browser, work fine.

But if I open it with curl, I get error:

> php curl Failed to connect to xxx port 5001: Connection refused

My php code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://xxx:5001/?messageId=2&baseId=1');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);;
print_r($res);
curl_close($ch);
```

Port 5001 is opened with firewall and IP not block by server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl : connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027340/curl-connection-refused)

Comment: @AngelDeykov actually it does not.  Resolving this issue for a localhost post is not the same quest as resolving this issue for a server sitting somewhere in internet lalaland.

Answer (score 0):

*I ran the code on my local machine and **it works**. Try the following:*

1. run the script on the command line `>PHP script.php` and check the errors
2. if you have access to the server check the log `#tail -f /var/log/error_log`
3. check for domain resolution. can the serve resolve the same name as your desktop/dev box?
4. repeat step 1 from the server.

**you will find the answer in one of those 4 steps.**

Comment: 3.1 check that the provider of this API has it set for the port you are using; 3.2) validate that you are using the right http method (GET vs POST) ; 3.3 check with the API provider that `http` is allowed vis `https`